# Trying to test Domain Collapsing / Consoldiation validity for SEO purposes

Tags: domain, seo

At work, we're trying to determine the effectiveness of domain collapsing for SEO purposes.  Our current structure is to have multiple web apps served from different servers, such as

```
PUBLIC URLS - directly accessed by users
www1.somecompany.com/webapp1
www2.somecompany.com/webapp2
www3.somecompany.com/webapp3
```

I'm proposing to put an Apache proxy in front of these applications that will mask the different domains and route the requests to proper server

```
PUBLIC URL--------routed/forwarded to-----PRIVATE URL
www.somecompany.com/webapp1   <----->  www1.somecompany.com/webapp1
www.somecompany.com/webapp2   <----->  www2.somecompany.com/webapp2
www.somecompany.com/webapp3   <----->  www3.somecompany.com/webapp3
```

In terms of SEO/page rank value, does this help?

Comment: I believe the folks over here will be able to give you the best answers: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The page rank value of each `/webappN` can be different, so you could just as well use subdomains and properly route each app to its own server via A records, without the need for proxying.